# Openvas - exploiting result

Tags: exploit, kali-linux

I am an IT administrator and I try at present to secure my network. I have made an analysis of safety with OpenVAS on one computer, and I have difficulty exploiting the result :

```
Vulnerability Detection Result

Distributed Computing Environment (DCE) services running on the remote host
can be enumerated by connecting on port 135 and doing the appropriate queries.

An attacker may use this fact to gain more knowledge
about the remote host.

Here is the list of DCE services running on this host:

Port: 49152/tcp

UUID: d95afe70-a6d5-4259-822e-2c84da1ddb0d, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49152]

Port: 49153/tcp

UUID: f6beaff7-1e19-4fbb-9f8f-b89e2018337c, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49153]
Annotation: Event log TCPIP

UUID: 30adc50c-5cbc-46ce-9a0e-91914789e23c, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49153]
Annotation: NRP server endpoint

UUID: 3c4728c5-f0ab-448b-bda1-6ce01eb0a6d6, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49153]
Annotation: DHCPv6 Client LRPC Endpoint

UUID: 3c4728c5-f0ab-448b-bda1-6ce01eb0a6d5, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49153]
Annotation: DHCP Client LRPC Endpoint

UUID: 06bba54a-be05-49f9-b0a0-30f790261023, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49153]
Annotation: Security Center

Port: 49154/tcp

UUID: 86d35949-83c9-4044-b424-db363231fd0c, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]

UUID: 552d076a-cb29-4e44-8b6a-d15e59e2c0af, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: IP Transition Configuration endpoint

UUID: 98716d03-89ac-44c7-bb8c-285824e51c4a, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: XactSrv service

UUID: 201ef99a-7fa0-444c-9399-19ba84f12a1a, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: AppInfo

UUID: 5f54ce7d-5b79-4175-8584-cb65313a0e98, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: AppInfo

UUID: fd7a0523-dc70-43dd-9b2e-9c5ed48225b1, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: AppInfo

UUID: 58e604e8-9adb-4d2e-a464-3b0683fb1480, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49154]
Annotation: AppInfo

Port: 49155/tcp

UUID: 12345778-1234-abcd-ef00-0123456789ac, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49155]
Named pipe : lsass
Win32 service or process : lsass.exe
Description : SAM access

Port: 49169/tcp

UUID: 367abb81-9844-35f1-ad32-98f038001003, version 2
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49169]

Port: 49177/tcp

UUID: 0b6edbfa-4a24-4fc6-8a23-942b1eca65d1, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49177]
Annotation: Spooler function endpoint

UUID: ae33069b-a2a8-46ee-a235-ddfd339be281, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49177]
Annotation: Spooler base remote object endpoint

UUID: 76f03f96-cdfd-44fc-a22c-64950a001209, version 1
Endpoint: ncacn_ip_tcp:192.168.1.30[49177]
Annotation: Spooler function endpoint

Solution : filter incoming traffic to this port(s).

Solution

filter incoming traffic to this port.
Vulnerability Detection Method

Details: DCE Services Enumeration (OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.25623.1.0.10736)

Version used: $Revision: 41 $
```

- How can I verify all services?
- Is the computer infected by one or several viruses?

Comment: Do you want to _exploit_ the result, or _interpret_ it? If you mean to exploit it, do you have a specific exploit in mind?

Answer (score 3):

An important thing to note about Vulnerability scanners such as OpenVAS and Nessus, is that not all of the things they report are easily exploitable vulnerabilities.

In a lot of cases all they are doing is providing information about a host which could be useful to the tester or attacker in understanding the system and allowing them to execute other attacks.

In this case what you're seeing is an enumeration of Windows services which are accessible via DCE, there's nothing in that finding to say that they're vulnerable, and what you're seeing is quite typical for a local windows server (if that port (135/TCP) is open to the Internet, that would be a bit concerning as that's rarely needed or a good idea)

Verifying those services would be most easily done by reviewing the services running on the host with appropriate credentials, and stopping/disabling any which are not needed for the operation of the service.

As to your second point, there is nothing in that output which would appear to clearly indicate that your machine is infected by a virus.